# How to read a column from a text file in java using scanner?

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I have this text that I want to read the first column from in my project named Data.txt.

```
//column names:   productId, name,numInStock,provider,pricePerUnit

private static String records =     "231A,Light Bulb,123,Wilco,1.75:"+
                                "113D,Hairbrush,19,Aamco,3.75:"+
                                "521W,Shampoo,24,Acme,6.95:"+
                                "440Q,Dishwashing Detergent,20,Wilco,1.75:"+
                                "009G,Toothbrush,77,Wilco,0.85:"+
                                "336C,Comb,34,Wilco,0.99:"+
                                "523E,Paper Pad Set,109,Congdon and Chrome,2.45:"+
                                "888A,Fake Diamond Ring,111,Americus Diamond,3.95:"+
                                "176A,Romance Nove1 1,20,Barnes and Noble,3.50:"+
                                "176B,Romance Nove1 2,20,Barnes and Noble,3.50:"+
                                "176C,Romance Nove1 3,20,Barnes and Noble,3.50:"+
                                "500D,Floss,44,Wilco,1.25:"+
                                "135B,Ant Farm,5,Wilco,8.00:"+
                                "211Q,Bicycle,9,Schwinn,75.95:"+
                                "932V,Pen Set,50,Congdon and Chrome,9.95:"+
                                "678Q,Pencil 50,123,Congdon and Chrome,9.95:"+
                                "239A,Colored Pencils,25,Congdon and Chrome,4.75:"+
                                "975B,Shower Curtain,25,Wilco,6.50:"+
                                "870K,Dog Bowl,15,Wilco,4.75:"+
                                "231S,Cat Bowl,15,Wilco,4.75:"+
                                "562M,Kitty Litter,15,Wilco,3.25:"+
                                "777X,Dog Bone,15,Wilco,4.15:"+
                                "933W,Cat Toy,15,Wilco,2.35:"+
                                "215A,Hair Ball,0,Little Jimmy,0.00:";
```

I wrote this code to do so but I am not getting the desired output.
My code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\student\\Desktop\\workspace\\Welcome\\src\\Data.txt");
        input = new Scanner(file);

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] words = line.split(",");
            System.out.println(words[0]);
            input.useDelimiter(",");
        }
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to get the output in this format

```
               134A
               213A
               911C
               012E
               662Z
```

This is the output I got I want to remove the part that says private static String records = and also the ".

```
//column names:   productId

private static String records =     "231A
                                "113D
                                "521W
                                "440Q
                                "009G
                                "336C
                                "231S
```

Comment: `private static String records = ...` is the file's content ? If that's so, you should split with `:` instead of a comma `,` first to get your lines and then you split with the comma each line and get the first item in each array.

Comment: Also since this is a .txt file, the `private static String records =` isn't required, nor is the quotes `" ... "` and `+` which can add confusion to the work you're doing.

Comment: Yes it is the content of the file I want to extract the first column

Comment: Henry Tang I cannot edit the text file

Comment: Just to confirm ... does the file *really* consist of a single line?   Without any newlines?  Because that is what the `records` string says.  (And it is actually rather important that we know *exactly* what the input file looks like.  Because that determines how it should be read.)

Comment: @StephenC the file has multiple lines with newline between each line as I have put it in the first part of the question. I just put the input file

Comment: So ... the file that you are reading contains Java source code?   Really?  (Sounds a bit crazy to me ...)

Comment: @StephenC The first code block is the text file that I want to read from

Comment: And the file contains no newlines?  Is that correct?   Because `record` contains no newlines.  (If your file >does< contain newlines, then Matt22's answer won't work *for the file*.)

Comment: The file contains newlines and Matt's code prints out the newlines as they are It is not fully working yes

Comment: Well yes.  As I have been trying to point out in my comments, your question is unclear.  It has described the file content by means of a Java string expression.  But the string expression you provided does not match the actual file content.  You need to EDIT the question to put the >>real<< file content in there (rather than that fictitious string representation).  Then maybe someone can give you an answer that works with your file.

Comment: This is not Matt's fault.  His answer is correct for the question that you asked.  It works for that string.  The problem is that you haven't asked the correct question; i.e. a question that matches your real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sort-of on the right track with the delimeters.
Here's how I did it and it can be cleaned up a bit, and you'll have to make a for loop to iterate through the arraylist and get each one, and split each one and print each one's 0'th index ( "str" is the string/text file you provided )

```
          Scanner in = new Scanner(str) ;
      in.useDelimiter(":") ;
      ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>() ;
      while( in.hasNext())
      {
          al.add(in.next() ) ;
      }
      
      for( int i = 0 ; i < al.size(); ++i )
      {
          String s = al.get(i) ;
          String[] s2 = s.split(",") ;
          System.out.println( s2[0] );
      }
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it is not working for me

Comment: I attached the for loop now. You can't do `s2[i]` since the s2 array is only like 5 long. It has to be a static 0 (the first column)

Comment: @SamuelMideksa - Please be more specific.

Comment: @MattDog_222Overwatch Now it works but I still get this character " and also the "+ character in the output

Comment: I would double check that you don't have any extra code running somewhere in it because I don't have any extra characters being added. There should be no literal "+" anywhere because the string doesn't contain any.

Comment: `//column names
   productId
"+
         "113D` I am getting this
"+

Comment: Is the "productID, etc etc" header part of the same file?

Comment: yes it is the header part it is not to be in the output

Comment: If the header is on a separate line you can just do `scan.nextLine() ;` to consume it off the top, otherwise you'll have to get a bit fancier

Comment: @MattDog_222Overwatch Is `scan.nextLine() ;` it on the while loop?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your response. Umm, if the text file has the headers on a line, and all the data on a next line (2 text lines total), you can get rid of the first line with calling ` scan.nextLine() ` before the loops and just act like its not there. Otherwise, make it equal to ` str.substring(48) ` before the loops, and that'll remove the first 48 characters from the string, assuming the start is exactly "productId, name,numInStock,provider,pricePerUnit"